# Javascript Global variables

Tags: javascript, variables, global

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
var toggle;
toggle=1;
function open(){
jQuery(window).bind("beforeunload", function(){$.post("logout.php");})
$.post("online.php",function(data){
$("#Layer6").html(data);
});
}

function toggle() 
{
$("#Layer4").animate({height:'toggle'});
$("#Layer6").animate({height:'toggle'});

if(toggle==1)
{
$("#toggle").attr('src',"toggle_up.jpg");
toggle=0;
}
else
{
$("#toggle").attr('src',"toggle_down.jpg");
toggle=1; 
}  

}

</script>
```

Here i have defined toggle as a global variable,and set its value to be 1 initially.
When toggle() is executed,the value of toggle should change as its a global variable.Upon execution,the script doesn't seem to work at all(the toggle part).

Kindly help. Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

You've named your variable and function the same name ("toggle"). The function definition is overriding your variable declaration (since it comes afterward). Rename your function to something else, e.g. `doToggle()`.

The reason that this conflict occurs is because you can assign function objects to variables in Javascript. Basically, when you call a function, Javascript looks for either a function with that name, or a variable with that name, in case it holds a reference to a function:

```
var variable = 3;
variable = function() { alert('Function called') };
variable();     // Calls the function, whose reference is stored in 'variable'
```

Answer (score 0):

As Cameron pointed out the problem is that the variable and the function have the same name.

Also, keep in mind that jQuery has a method called **[`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)**... This won't cause a conflict, since that's a method of `$` or `jQuery`... but it might confuse someone reading your code.

Anyway, here is a more compact way to solve your problem:

```
var count = 1;

function toggle() 
{

    $("#Layer4").animate({height:'toggle'});
    $("#Layer6").animate({height:'toggle'});

    $("#toggle").attr('src',"toggle_" + (count++ % 2 ? "up" : "down") + ".jpg");

}
```

### **[jsFiddle example page](http://jsfiddle.net/8d6wD/)**

The above uses the **[Javascript conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Special_Operators/Conditional_Operator)** to either concatenate `up` or `down` into the `src` attribute of `#toggle`.

`(count++ % 2 ? "up" : "down")` will first take count's current value (and then it increments its value) and mod it by 2. This value will either be 1 or 0. If it's 1 (true), `up` is concatenated. If it's 0 (false), `down` is concatenated. The incrementing is to keep track of the toggle.

As a note you can wrap your variables, functions, and any jQuery / other code that makes use of either in a self executing anonymous function, so as to minimize mucking the global namespace and to reduce the chance of variable name clashes if you later add more scripts to the page.

```
(function() { 
    var count = 1;
    function open() { ... }
    function toggle() { ... }
    $(function() {
        ...
    });
}());
```